# Batch files won't run when combined (quitting ghostscript in a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, imagemagick, ghostscript

I have two batch files, both simple commands. Both work fine if I double click their icon. I'd like to merge them.

**Part 1**  looks like this: (%1 is the incoming PostScript from RedMon)

```
"c:\program files\gs\gs9.14\bin\gswin64c.exe" -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dSTRICT -dSAFER -sDEVICE=jpeg -r300 -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -o "c:\path\temp_label.jpg" %1
```

**Part 2** looks like this:

```
convert -quality 99 -density 300 -crop 1240x1760+110+100 -chop 0x200+0+900 -rotate 90 "c:\path\temp_label.jpg" "c:\path\temp_label_edit.jpg"

composite -gravity center "c:\users\mary\documents\labels\temp_label_edit.jpg" "c:\path\new_shipping_label.jpg" "c:\path\temp_label_small.jpg"

convert -quality 99 -density 300 -resize  3059 "c:\path\temp_label_small.jpg" "c:\path\temp_label_resize.jpg"

imdisplay /p "c:\path\temp_label_resize.jpg"
mspaint "c:\path\temp_label_resize.jpg"
```

Part 1 is a ghostscript command that just makes a jpg file from the incoming postscript. It's called by RedMon (using redrun.exe) when I print and works fine. Part 2 is imagemagick that crops the image, adds it to another layer, and shows me the result as a file as well as directing it to another (real) printer.

When I run just the first part, it gives me the file automagically when I print. If I double click the icon for part 2, it works. But what I'd like to do, since we run this at least 12 times/day, is to have them run from a single batch file.

**What it does:** When I merge the two batch files, the original file from GS is generated correctly. But then I get a message from both imdisplay and paint that "...temp_label_resize.jpg cannot be found."  But like I mentioned, if I run them separately, they work.

**What I've tried:**

1. Adding and eliminating -dBATCH et al. from the parameters passed to GhostScript
2. Putting pauses between the commands to give time to run, using the ping method
3. Keeping the files separate and calling them from a single file, i.e. 1.bat calls 2.bat and 3.bat. Same result.
4. Removing all variables except for %1 (code reflects this)
5. Putting a call to open the different file names immediately after creation: the only file that is created is the original temp_label.jpg
6. Run gswin64 rather than gswin64c - no glitches reported, still no imagemagick code executed.
7. Called convert from the cmd to ensure that I was getting the imagemagick's convert and not something else.

My assumption is that since the imagemagick files are never created there is a problem either with GhostScript ending or with my imagemagick code. However, my imagemagick code executes properly. Therefore, my guess is that GS isn't exiting properly.  I'm probably missing something obvious, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does gswin64.exe return immediately or after it has completed?  My initial suspicion would be that things are happening in parallel.

Comment: Ah just had another thought.  Does the environment for redrun.exe have the PATH set correctly to find convert and composite?  I notice you have specified the full path to gswin64c.exe

Comment: Guess our comments got crossed. That was the solution!

Original comment: Actually, they were running sequentially. But in checking that (using Start /Wait to pop up multiple boxes) I discovered the problem - While I can type convert on the command line and execute it in a stand-alone batch file, and 100% of the time get the imagemagick convert, it was, for some reason, calling the windows convert executable.

Comment: @GeekyDeaks - so I need to specify a separate PATH for each program? Because composite was called no problem.
Also, write up an answer and I'll mark it. Thanks!

Comment: Usually when a program is launched, it inherits the environment of it's parent.  I assume that redrun.exe/RedMon is launched via the print spool service, so it would pickup it's environment including the PATH from the service. This can be (and appears to be in your case) different to the environment you get from launching CMD.  Personally, I would just specify the full path the all commands to be 100% sure you know what is going on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the PATH environment variable for redrun.exe is not the same as that when you start a command prompt.  I would recommend you specify the path to each command in full, similar to what you have done for gswin64c.exe, e.g.

```
"c:\program files\gs\gs9.14\bin\gswin64c.exe" ....
"c:\program files\ImageMagick\bin\convert.exe" ....
```

etc..etc..

This way you can be 100% sure that you are running the correct executable.

Comment: Thanks - that was exactly it. I didn't realize the print spooler would have a different PATH than other programs. It appears that maybe it still has access to the "regular" PATH (since I can get composite without writing out the path) but maybe they're in a different order, as suggested here: [link](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=19679)

Comment: I think you are most probably right.  If you are feeling curious, you could `echo %PATH%` during the batch file and compare it to that from CMD.  I find this kinda funny as I am not very au-fait with windows, but this very same problem bites me in bum about once a year under unix when I start mucking with cron :)

Comment: Nice thought by the echoed paths are the same (too long to post here). Glad to hear it's not a win-only problem. :P